# Content that is too large for the page is not pushed to the next page

Tags: xsl-fo

I've got a layout-master-set with this as the definition for the first page in my book:

```
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page_first" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin="{$page-margin}"> 
            <fo:region-body region-name="body"margin-top="180mm" margin-bottom="40mm"
                margin-left="10mm" margin-right="10mm" padding="0pt" column-number="2" column-gap="20mm" />
            <fo:region-before region-name="header-odd" extent="180mm" precedence="true"/>
            <fo:region-after region-name="footer-odd-first" extent="40mm" precedence="true"/>
            <fo:region-start region-name="regStartFirst" extent="10mm"/>
            <fo:region-end region-name="regEndFirst" extent="10mm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
```

So this leaves 297-180-40 = 77 mm height for the body area. The body area has 2 columns, 85 mm wide each.

In my XML file, the first object to be placed on this page is a graphic that's 100x100 mm. In the FO I process this image to fit inside the column width, and the resulting image frame has a width set, but the height is only specified via 'scale-down-to-fit':

```
<fo:external-graphic src="image.pdf" width="85mm" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" scaling="uniform" scaling-method="auto"/>
```

This external graphic is placed inside a couple of blocks that don't have any width or height settings.

When I render my XML in Antennahouse, the image is displayed on the first page, where it extends into the footer area. I would expect the image to be pushed to the second page (which has a larger body area where the image would fit).
How can I get the image to be placed correctly? I've tried to set the height manually, but that doesn't help. When I replace the image with text, the text flows correctly (i.e. no overlap).

**edit**: I've done some tests. As soon as I place a block with some text before the image block, the image is moved to the second page. So could this be an Antennahouse bug where it always tries to render the first content block on the first page, regardless of size?

Comment: If you uniformly scale a 100mm x 100mm image to be 85mm wide, it will be 85mm high.  Since that fits inside your 97mm, how can it overflow the footer?

Comment: I see I simplified my data too much, I've added in the missing bits.

Comment: The formatter is probably trying to avoid an infinite loop by placing at least some content in each page (even if it overflows the body region), otherwise this could happen: the image does not fit in page 1, let's just create an empty page 1 and try again; oops, it still does not fit in page 2, let's make another empty page and try again; mhh, it still does not fit in page 3 ... Counter-example: if you have block of text + image, and every page is like the first one, you should get page 1 with the text, and page 2 with the overflowing image.

Answer (score 0):

You can force it to the next page with `<fo:block break-before="even-page">` (or `odd-page`, depending on how you start your page sequences).  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#break-before.

Comment: Sure, but normally the FO processor takes care of that: any content that doesn't fit on a page gets moved to the next. I'm wondering why that's not working in this case?